# How to make mutually exclusive highlighted links with javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have tried this:

```
$(function() {  
  return $("a[data-sir-id]").click(function() {
    var data_sir_id;
    data_sir_id = $(this).data("sir-id");
    $("a[data-sir-id='" + data_sir_id + "']").addClass("underline");
  });
});
```

But I want to make the underline keep until another data-sir-id is clicked?

I have tried to `.removeClass` but don't know where to place it.

Also I want the underline to be mutually exclusive, i.e. only one link (the last to be clicked)  should be underlined.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to be returning in that code.  That is wrong. Also there is no reason to look up the id when you are currently on that element.

```
$(function() {  
  $("a[data-sir-id]").click(function() {
    $(".underline").removeClass("underline");  //remove the class from any element that has it
    $(this).addClass("underline");  //add a class to the currently clicked link
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello for the clear explanation. I understand what this does now, but why does not it work for the first click (when page is displayed for the first time or refreshed) ?

Comment: Does it still not work on the first click? It should be fine. Are you adding the code in a different manner?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something very quick:

```
$(function() {  
  $("a[data-sir-id]").click(function(e) {
      $("a[data-sir-id]").removeClass("underline");
      $(this).addClass("underline");
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Jsfiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WXraR/